# making these two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

Sorry for asking the same question which is asked many many times.. but my case seems to be a bit weird.. i checked all posts, but couldnot find a solution for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/pBPQ7/1/  this is my code.

I want to make `rightson` always stick to `leftson` even if you resize the window.

in my big screen, the rightson is going far to right side of screen leaving leftson in the middle. i want them to stick to each other always.. how is it possible in css? :(

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't be able to have a set `width` property on the `#father` `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a min-width to your #father and make your elements inline.

```
#father {
min-width:476px;
}
```

Check this code http://jsfiddle.net/pBPQ7/15/

Answer (score 1):

use

```
float: right
```

on both elements.

Comment: Be aware that using this solution will give the appearance that the divs have swapped order.

Comment: But it will break with the browsers size

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/pBPQ7/5/

Just add a

```
float:left;
```

to both.

Comment: But float will break with the browsers size

Comment: Yes that is the expected behavior. You will have to use % widths if you don't want it to happen, or use some of the alternative solutions other persons suggested. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make these divs with display: inline-block;

jsfiddle.net/pBPQ7/10/

Answer (score 1):

Check this:
you can add margin-right to your div and add width for your father div.

```
#father div {
display: table-cell;
}
#father {
display:table;
width:500px;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pBPQ7/17/

Answer (score 1):

Depend on what you want to do.

If you don't need to have a fix width for the left or the right column, you can add % on your items.

[Here is an example of what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/pBPQ7/19/)

**CSS**

```
#father{
    width:100%;
}

#leftson{
    width:65%; 
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E7E6E5;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px gray;
    float: left; 
}
#rightson{
    width:30%;
    float: left; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px gray;
}
```

Otherwise, you can float your content (with the same size). [Here is an other example](http://jsfiddle.net/pBPQ7/24/)

Another possibility, If you have a fixed div in width, you can resize only the other one when resizing. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/pBPQ7/25/)